# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8

I am following a video on LinkedIn learning, and when I try to run my code, I get the following error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` and I have looked at the files and don't see this '<' on line 1 as the error says.  This error results in a fix for a `Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.` where I added `type="text/javascript"` in front of the src. Line 1 of the first file I get the error for is `/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap` and as you can see there is no < in that line.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Here is the code in question:

````
    <script src="runtime-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
    <script src="polyfills-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="styles-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="styles-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="vendor-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="main-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>```
any of the scripts with type="module" are the issues.
````

Comment: so sounds like something is returning html error page and not a javascript file

Comment: Impossible to say without knowing your setup, or your code. That error has been asked about many times on Stack Overflow and is almost always the server responding with a 404 or other error page instead of the code you think should be served...

Comment: This error very commonly happens when an AJAX request is expected to return JSON and instead returns HTML.  Check your network requests/responses.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are making an HTTP request and it is returning the entire webpage instead of the data you are looking for because of an error in the request.  So the first character in the response is `<` which is part of the `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of the html file that is coming back in the response.  If you show us a sample of your code that is making this request I could be more specific.